# Is it possible to assign multiple values in an enumeration? Swift language

Tags: swift, enums, associated-types

I did something like this:

```
enum DollarCountries: String { 
    case usa = "USA", //Countries Where the U.S. Dollar
    case australia = "Australia" //Countries Where the Australian Dollar        
    case canada = "Canada" //Countries Where the Canadian Dollar
}
```

And I need to make it like that:

```
enum DollarCountries: String { 
    case usa = "USA", "Palau", "Panama"
    case australia = "Australia", "Kiribati", "Nauru"
    case canada = "Canada"
}
```

I tried to do this, but it didn't work :c

```
enum DollarCountries: [String] {
...
}
```

Comment: You can use computed property in enums like this. `var states : [String] { ["Palau","Panama"] }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No , enum can't have multiple raw values.But , you can use competed property like that

```
enum DollarCountries1{
    case usa(String?)
    var storedDollar : [String]  {
        ["USA","Australia","Canada"]
    }

    var moneyType : String{
        switch self {
        case .usa(let str):
            if storedDollar.contains(str!){
                return "Dollar";
            }
            return "none"
        default:
            return "none"
        }
     }

}

let country = "USA"
var forUsa = DollarCountries1.usa(country)
print(forUsa.moneyType)
```

Answer (score 2):

As has been said, you can't have multiple rawValues for each enum case, and you also can't have an Array of values as the rawValue

How to proceed depends a lot on how the code is being used. If your intention is to go from `String` to your `enum` you can facilitate this with a custom initialiser

```
enum DollarCountries {
    case usa, australia, canada
}

extension DollarCountries {

    init?(_ rawValue: String) {
        switch rawValue {
            case "USA", "Palau", "Panama":
                self = .usa

            case "Australia", "Kiribati", "Nauru":
                self = .australia

            case "Canada":
                self = .canada

            default:
                return nil
        }
    }
}

let a = DollarCountries("USA")      // .usa
let b = DollarCountries("Kiribati") // .australia
let c = DollarCountries("UK")       // nil
```

if you mainly want to go the other way round, a computed property is all you need:

```
extension DollarCountries {

    var nations: [String] {
        switch self {
            case .usa:
                return ["USA", "Palau", "Panama"]

            case .australia:
                return ["Australia", "Kiribati", "Nauru"]

            case .canada:
                return ["Canada"]
        }
    }
}
```

If you need both, I'll leave it to you to find a way to implement this without duplicating the arrays

P.S: For the `nations` computed property, I highly recommend you use `Set` if the ordering is not important